# Android - LVL library always returns NOT_LICENSED

Tags: android, licensing, android-lvl

My app that I created in 2016 has LVL library, to check the licensing (I added the LVL library to it in 2022).

A few days ago, my app (debug version) stopped working in my phone because of the library: it now always returns NOT_LICENSED, even though my Google account is listed as licensing test account, and the result in the play console is LICENSED:

[image: Licensing test result]

I tried a lot of solutions I found here in SO: reset the value of the Licensing response in the Play console, clear data of the Google Play app in my phone, restart the phone...etc.
But nothing worked.

I'm now also worried that users are also experiencing this problem, even though I didn't have negative comments yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contacted Google Play support yesterday, and it seems like LVL's response is working properly today. Any changes on your side?

Comment: You're right! It's working now